# Angular and RxJs combine two http requests

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ecmascript-6, rxjs

I am making two http requests, each return a `observable<IProduct>;` and I want to combine both into a local object and use the **async pipe** to bring values from each.

```
productA$: observable<IProduct>;
productB$: observable<IProduct>;
combinedProds$: ?

this.productA$ = httpCall();
this.productB$ = httpCall();


  this.combinedProds$ = combineLatest([
  this.productA$,
  this.productB$
   ])
  .pipe(
    map(([productA, productB]) =>
      ({ productA, productB}))
  );
```

This issue I'm getting, I don't know what type `combinedProds$` should be.

Comment: Define an `interface` called, may-be `IProductPair` and map to that type.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Maybe [forkJoin](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/combination/forkjoin) is the one you are looking for ?

forkJoin work best with Http call and I'm using it a lot when dealing with http request

```
// RxJS v6.5+
import { ajax } from 'rxjs/ajax';
import { forkJoin } from 'rxjs';

/*
  when all observables complete, provide the last
  emitted value from each as dictionary
*/
forkJoin(
  // as of RxJS 6.5+ we can use a dictionary of sources
  {
    google: ajax.getJSON('https://api.github.com/users/google'),
    microsoft: ajax.getJSON('https://api.github.com/users/microsoft'),
    users: ajax.getJSON('https://api.github.com/users')
  }
)
  // { google: object, microsoft: object, users: array }
  .subscribe(console.log);
```

Update

forkJoin return an `Observable<any>` so you can change your like this

`combinedProds$: Observable<any>`

Comment: Thanks for the reply, the issue I'm getting, what type should the `combinedProds$` variable be?

Comment: observable<any> works, but I'd have thought something like observable<IProduct[]> would work here too, if I wanted to 'strongly type' it?

Comment: Yes I understand but the forkJoin return an array of Observable

Comment: This works :)  If I get the `type` solved, I will post an update here. Thanks again.